# How to implement id based FullCalendar views?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, fullcalendar

I am building an MVC project that tracks vacation days used by employees. I have web grid that will display vacation days taken based on "employeeID". I would like to be able to display these dates using FullCalendar for a single employee at a time. Currently I can display all employees or none. I am very new to this and would like further guidance. 
My Code so far....
Employee Model

```
`public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last name is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "First Name Middle Initial")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return FirstMidName + " " + LastName;
        }
    }
    public virtual ICollection<Vacation> Vacation { get; set; }
}`
```

Vacation Model

```
 ` public class Vacation
    {

        public int VacationID { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public int VacationCodeID { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
        public int Hours { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }

        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
        public virtual VacationCode VacationCode { get; set; }
    }`
```

VacationController

```
//
    // GET: /Vacation/
    public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "id")]int employeeId)
    {
        var Employee = db.Employees.Find(employeeId);
        if (Employee != null)
        {
            return View(Employee);
        }
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

public ActionResult Calendar()
    {

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult List(long start, long end)
    {
        var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        var startDate = epoch.AddMilliseconds(start);
        var endDate = epoch.AddMilliseconds(end);

        var ctx = new FullCalendarTestContext();
        var data = ctx.Vacations
        .Where(i => startDate <= i.EventDate && i.EventDate <= endDate)
        .GroupBy(i => i.EventDate)
        .Select(i => new { EventDate = i.Key, VacationCodeID = i.FirstOrDefault() }).Take(20).ToList();

        return Json(data.Select(i => new
        {
            title = (i.VacationCodeID.VacationCode.VacationType != null) ? i.VacationCodeID.VacationCode.VacationType : "Untitled",
            start = i.EventDate.ToShortDateString(),
            allDay = true
        }));
    }
```

Vacation Index View:

```
    @model FullCalendarTest.Models.Employee

<h1>@Model.FullName</h1>

<hr />

@Html.Partial("_Partial1", Model.Vacation)

    @model IEnumerable<FullCalendarTest.Models.Vacation>


<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
@{
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model, rowsPerPage: 10, canPage: true, canSort: true, defaultSort: "EventDate");
    grid.SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
}

@grid.GetHtml(columns: new[]{

grid.Column("Employee.FullName", "Name" ),
grid.Column("VacationCode.VacationType","Vacation Code"),
grid.Column("EventDate", "Date",format: (item) => string.Format("{0:MMM-dd-yy}", item.EventDate)),
grid.Column("Hours","Hours"),
grid.Column("Notes","Notes"),
grid.Column("",
header:"Edit Options",
format: @<text>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.VacationID })
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.VacationID })
</text>
)
})
```

Calendar View:

```
    @model FullCalendarTest.Models.Vacation

@section scripts{
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/fullcalendar.css")"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/fullcalendar.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            eventClick: function (i, evt, view) {
            },
                              events: function (start, end, callback) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: '@Url.Action("List", "Vacation")?start=' + start.getTime().toString() + "&end=" + end.getTime().toString(),
                    success: function (d) {
                        var list = [];
                        for (var i = 0, len = d.length; i < len; i++) {
                            var item = d[i];
                            item.start = new Date(item.start);
                            list.push(item);
                        }

                        callback(list);
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        debugger;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
}
<h2>Calendar</h2>
<div id='calendar' style="width: 75%"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to :

- add an extra `employeeId` on the controller side, and use it in the query, something along the line :

  ```
  .Where(i => i.employeeId == employeeId && startDate <= ...
  ```
- add the parameter to the request, on the javascript side :

  ```
  events: function(...){
      // Get the expected employeeId from some source :
      // an html node, a specific attribute, a javascript variable ...
      // For example, if the "displayed employee" is chosen from a select :
      var employeeId = $('#selectEmployee').val(); 
      $.ajac({
          url: '@Action...?employeeId='+employeeId+'&start='+...

      })
  }
  ```

Comment: I have not had any luck with this yet. I would like to pass the EmployeeID to the calendar in a similar fashion as the "index" to Detail" view.

Comment: @Hugh: what do you mean by `the "index" to Detail" view` ?

Comment: The "Index" passes the EmployeeID to the "detail" and provides data relevant only to that employee. Similar to the Vacation Controller above, The index collects the EmployeeID and the wbgrid only shows the vacation dates to for that employee in the partial view.

Comment: It took quite awhile for me to fully understand how to implement your suggestion, when I did it worked wonderfully. The final component to passing the ID was using the Html.HiddenFor helper.